# Ctrl+Alt+T - shortcut not working

Tags: shortcuts

I tried the keyboard settings. Currently running on ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS,
recently installed elementary theme in it, later uninstalled. Whenever 
I try to use the shortcut there is no response.

Answer (score 0):

You Must have disable the combo key somehow.
 I Assume you need the shortcut for opening terminal.
To Re-enable Ctr+Alt+T shortcut follow the following steps:
Step 1:

Goto settings and under Keyboard find the shortcut tab.
Step 2:

 
Under Launchers sections locate terminal, if not exist goto custom sections.
Click on the + sign a small window will pop up.

Step 3:

Fill in the boxes.[image]

In the name column write terminal or anything that helps you remember.
Under Command column write gnome-terminal

 Next click on Set Shortcut... and press Ctr + Alt + T.
If you click other keys mistakenly press esc to restart the key capturing method.

 That will do it. Now test your settings.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I have tried the solution you mentioned. The problem still not resolved.